# No module named pycrypto with Paramiko

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycrypto

On my Raspberry Pi I have installed Paramiko. When I installed it, it came up with an error, something like "pycrypto didn't install". I then used pip and easy_install to try and install pycrypto, but an error comes up with that, something like `failed with error code 1 in /root/build/crypto`

How can I install pycrypto?

I am using a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Wheezy.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!

I did: `sudo apt-get install python-dev` and then installed `pycrypto` again with `pip`. That worked!